# HTML Required Attribute

Tags: html

I understand that required attribute is used, if you want the field to be filled up, however, it can only work on computer browser but not for mobile browser. What particular code is needed for mobile browser to work too. Thanks

Comment: It works on *any* browser that supports it, including mobile browsers. Since not all browsers support it, if you want to enforce a field being filled, you need server-side validation (with optional client-side hinting).

Comment: There's no fundamental difference between desktop and mobile browsers. *The particular mobile browser you're testing with* doesn't support the attribute...?!

Comment: Prefer to add server side check of empty inputs

Comment: or use javascript to check

Comment: i am using google chrome on my ipad, however, it is still able to submit the form even though the field is not being filled.

Answer (score 0):

> i am using google chrome on my ipad, however, it is still able to submit the form even though the field is not being filled

Chrome on iOS is essentially just Safari in a different dress, and Safari doesn't support the `required` attribute. There is always the possibility of a browser not supporting a certain feature, so you should always check the compatibility matrix for the features you want to use, for example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility.

In cases where features aren't uniformly supported, you should be looking at *polyfills*, Javascript libraries you can include into your page which fill in the functionality if it's missing.

At no point should you be relying solely on browser-side features for validation at all, you must always have server-side validation as the actual source of truth.